# EdgesGeometry: raycasting not accurate

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm using EdgesGeometry on PlaneGeometry and it seems it creates a larger hitbox in mouse events. This however, isn't evident when using CircleGeometry. I have the following:

```
    createPanel = function(width, height, widthSegments) {

      var geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(width, height, widthSegments);

      var edges = new THREE.EdgesGeometry( geometry );

      var panel = new THREE.LineSegments( edges, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({ 
      color: 0xffffff }));

      return panel;

    }

   var tile = createPanel(1.45, .6, 1);
```

Now I'm using a library called RayInput which does all the raycasting for me but imagine I'm just using a normal raycaster for mouse events. Without the `edges` and using just the plane, the boundaries of collision is accurate.

After adding EdgesGeometry, the vertical hitbox seems to has increased dramatically thus, the object is detected being clicked when I'm not even clicking on it. The horizontal hitbox seems to have increased only slightly. I've never used EdgesGeometry before so anyone have a clue what is going on?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `raycaster.linePrecision = 0.1;`

Comment: Thanks, this worked to an extent but still wasn't accurate enough. I just ended putting a normal invisible plane as a hit box behind the outlined shape as a fix.

Comment: What do you mean it wasn't accurate enough?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. The raycaster is working as expected in this scenario which is detecting the edges. But for my personal case, adding another hitbox is the way to go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are raycasting against `THREE.Line` or `THREE.LineSegments`, you should set the `Line.threshold` parameter to a value appropriate to the scale of your scene:

```
raycaster.params.Line.threshold = 0.1; // default is 1
```

three.js r.114